# convert JavaObject `scala.collection.Map<Object,RDD<?>>` to python dictionary

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

In pyspark, calling the `getPersistentRDDs()` Java sparkContext method returns a JavaObject instance of `scala.collection.Map<Object,RDD<?>>`.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import StorageLevel

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

df = spark.range(0, 25000000, 1)
df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
df.limit(1).count()

sc._jsc.sc().getPersistentRDDs()
```

returns `JavaObject id=o477`

How can I convert a JavaObject of `scala.collection.Map<Object,RDD<?>>` into a python dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pyspark import RDD

scala_map = sc._jsc.sc().getPersistentRDDs()
py_dict = {e._1(): RDD(e._2().toJavaRDD(), sc) for e in [scala_map.toList().apply(i) for i in range(scala_map.size())]}
```